# I need to Ctrl-C/Pause after every manage.py command in Django

Tags: python, django, cmd, django-extensions

No, I'm not talking about runserver listening for requests.
Whenever i run makemigrations, migrate or scripts i wrote using django-extensions command runscript, I need to stop the execution of the program before typing in another. This was not the case before restarting my PC this morning.

I'm building a small QR code ticketing app and it was working up until this morning. I fixed a bug regarding opencv since and the app is functional again, but this command line issue is bothering me. I'm going to have to make the /admin and scripts available to a few of my colleagues tomorrow and i'm afraid we won't know when the script running is actually done since it doesn't prompt or allow another command. Having a script executed terminated early because of this would be catastrophic.

whenever i run a command, the blank line not accepting input appears

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's way too much possible reasons why this could've happened; and it's impossible for anyone else to reproduce your scenario just based on what you described. This isn't a widespread issue, so it must something particular to do with your setup.

Run a debugger, like pudb or pdb to find out where the script is stuck on.

Or add a try-except block to catch KeyboardInterrupt to your manage.py and use [traceback library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to narrow down where it's stuck.